# Using the Date Object in an Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object

I need to display a date from an array and it needs to be incremented for each input by 1 day. The date should display as mm/dd/yyyy. I was able to get the date to display correctly with the code that is in the message but after each input the all the dates would increment. I need just the last input to increment a day and I thought putting it in an array would work but now nothing displays. Thanks for helping.

```
var lowTempArray = []; 
var highTempArray = [];
var nowArray = [];

function process() {
    'use strict';

 //declare variables
    var lowTemp = document.getElementById('lowTemp'); 
    var highTemp = document.getElementById('highTemp');

    var output = document.getElementById('output');
 var date = new Date();

 var message = ' '; 

 if (lowTemp.value) {
 lowTempArray.push(lowTemp.value); 
    if (highTemp.value) {
     highTempArray.push(highTemp.value); 
          message = '<table><th>Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Low Temperatures</th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; High Temperatures</th>';
           for (var i = 0, count = lowTempArray.length; i < count; i++) {
               for (var i = 0, count = highTempArray.length; i < count; i++) {
                    for (var i = 0, count = nowArray.length; i < count; i++) { 
                        nowArray.push(new Date(date.getTime()));
                        date.setDate(date.getDate() + count); 
                       message += '<tr><td>' + ((nowArray.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (nowArray.getDate() + count) + '/' +  nowArray.getFullYear()) + '</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + lowTempArray[i] + '</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +  highTempArray[i]  + '</td></tr>';
                        }
                    message += '</table>';
                    output.innerHTML = message;
                    }

            } 
        }
    }
    return false;

}
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = process;
} // End of init() function.
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: -because this is for a javascript class and we have to use the Date object

Comment: Note: you're reusing the variable `i` in three loops, this will endup in unexpected results if not intended (inner loop incrementor modifies outer loops `i`). The phrase `new Date(date.getTime())` is probably redundant since `date` contains the current milliseconds, passed to `new Date()` creates a `Date`-object at that time (which has not changed significantly during run of `process`). Finally `nowArray.getMonth()` is wrong since `nowArray` is an array not a `Date`-object. Pro-Tip: avoid too much nesting (you can archive this by returning as early as possible on the inverse condition).

Comment: @ try-catch-finally I have updated my code with your suggestions but

Comment: Thanks for your help the Date object is incrementing now.